# how to attribute an event to an element of a listView

Tags: android, android-listview, event-handling

How can I attribute an event to a specified element ( position 0 for example ) of a listView ? I've tried this but it doesn't work :

```
ListView liste ;
liste.setOnItemClickListener( itemClickedListener );
```

Any help please ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code will only work if you initialize a new `onCItemClickListener`. Try this:

```
 liste.setOnItemClickListener( new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
             //do somthing
        });
    }
```

Comment: I've did that, but, is there any other way to make a treatment according the position of the clicked item ? ( not a switch ... case ... )

Comment: You'll need to implement a custom list adapter. here is a good tutorial: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-listview-with-adapter-example.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an adapter that backs the list, then set an OnItemClickListener object for the List. When the user clicks an individual entry in the list, the system calls OnItemClickListener.onItemClick, passing in the listed arguments:

- AdapterView<> arg0 is the ListView
- View arg1 is the entry in the ListView
- int arg2 (position) is the index of the data in the backing adapter, relative to 0
- long arg3 (rowId) is the row ID of the item that was clicked (not always useful).

To attribute the click to a specified element, look at position. This will give you a pointer to the data underlying the View that was clicked. This pointer is usually what you're looking for. For example, if your ListView is backed by a Cursor from a database or content provider, position will give you a pointer to the row in the Cursor.